# Python : Unable to create file name in the directory folder. Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, directory

```
 import datetime as dt
 import os  

valuation_date = (pd.to_datetime('01-Jan-2019').strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))
outdir = os.mkdir("C:\\users\\" + valuation_date)
file_name = 'imp'+'.csv'
out_file_name = open(outdir + file_name,'w')
```

Above is the code am implementing but I am unable to create file_name in the outdir. Its throwing error as 
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Please suggest.

Comment: `mkdir` doesn't seem to return anything. What's your intent there?

Comment: `os.mkdir()` does not return the directory name, therefore `outdir` is `None`.

Comment: I want to create a folder based on valuation_date as name and all my output csv files should go to this folder(not specified here) including file_name. How to do that ?

Comment: You also probably need a directory separator between `outdir` and `file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `outdir` variable first, and then pass that value into `mkdir()`:

```
outdir = "C:\\users\\" + valuation_date
os.mkdir(outdir)
```

This way, `outdir` retains its original value and you can refer to it again later in the program.

Comment: unable to create 'file_name'(refer above) in os.mkdir(outdir)

Comment: That doesn't tell us enough about the error.  What is the actual directory that it had an error with?